# R - Formating two different list the same way

Tags: r, list

I'm still new to R and I'm trying to compare two lists in order to get all differences between them (123 and 965 not present in list2) using setdiff().

How could I format them the same way in order to be able to compare them?

```
> list1
$<NA>
[1] "123"

$<NA>
[1] "8"

$<NA>
[1] "965"

$<NA>
[1] "789"

$<NA>
[1] "23"

>list2
        V1
1  8
2  22
3  11111
4  789
```

Comment: Maybe you can compare `unlist(list1)` with `list2$V1`? You'll be comparing two vectors. `list2` looks like a `data.frame` though...

Comment: @Thomas can you provide the `code` which generates your lists?

Comment: you did not provide the correct info for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salman is right in that you can't just blindly compare lists, because they are by design very heterogenous structures. But if you're confident that both lists are supposed to contain numbers and want to treat each list as one big undifferentiated sack, you can flatten and apply type conversion before doing the `setdiff()`

```
list1 <- as.list(as.character(c(123, 8, 965, 789, 23)))
names(list1) <- NA

list2 <- data.frame(V1=c(8, 22, 11111, 789))

listdiff <- function(x, y) {
    setdiff(as.numeric(unlist(x)), as.numeric(unlist(y)))
}

listdiff(list1, list2)
# [1] 123 965  23
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I needed !